# In C, Can two false (zero)'s be true together?

Tags: c++, boolean-logic

I know that a statement only works if the it evaluates to true by any means such as `OR/AND`.

I don't understand why computers can't understand this well at least C++.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    if(false && false)
        printf("true\n");
    else
        printf("false\n");
    return 0;
}
```

> Output: false

I know that looking at that code you quickly see that 2 falses and it will be false.

But what if they both became false together as a AND operator doesn't that make them true? not trying to the `NOT` operator here just don't understand why 2 false's checked together and both give the same output don't make a true?

Now that I wrote more about this seems like it would break alot of programs hehe..

I guess I just wondered into a different way of thinking for a split second and I didn't understand why it didn't work that way.

EDIT: yaa i guess i'll be receiving a bunch of downvotes I guess it's just simply how computers were built they don't have real logic

EDIT 2:

Okay I'll give you a example

Say you have to combine a bunch of packets together not to spam too much little packets.
But there is a catch if those small packets are too large you won't be able to combine them at all just send them as they are.
But lets say you already started combining packets and in the process a large packet arrises so you can't possiblely go on any further you have to quit here and send the current combined packet.

The problem arrises when to break out of the loop of packets in the list..

I am trying to avoid having 2 loops to check the list in advanced to know what to do trying to make it as optimized as possible very important to me.

So I got into a program

```
if(already building a combined packet boolean   AND    current_packet->size > MAX_COMBINE_PACKET)
  break;
else
  //don't try to combine the packets just send normally.
```

So in this situation  I haven't started combining packets and the packet size can fit into a combine packet.

But in this case it doesn't matter if the packet already started combining or hasn't started combining yet but still can be combined it will not try to combine it..

I guess I need to split it up into more if statements.

EDIT 3: the real code

```
/* pull packets from packet list into buf, and erase/free them */
static int pull_packets(packet_list_t *l, uint8_t *buf, bool cluster) {
    int bytes_placed = 0;
    int offset = 0;
    bool building_cluster = false;
    int MAX_CLUSTER_SIZE = 0xFF; //maybe make this a constant? 0xFF bytes is the payload max.

    while(l->begin() != l->end()) {
        PACKET *p = *l->begin();
        /* if you are building a cluster and the packet can't be clustered you can't send a regular packet anymore */
        /* otherwise just send it as a regular packet, ignore any clustering */
        if(building_cluster && p->len > MAX_CLUSTER_SIZE) 
            break; 
        else  //else if(!building_cluster && p->len > MAX_CLUSTER_SIZE)
            cluster = false;
        /* if theres room in the packet for cluster+cluster len+[packet] */
        if(cluster && p->len <= (MAX_PACKET - offset)) {
            if(!building_cluster) {
                //starts a new cluster packet 
                bytes_placed = build_packet( buf, "BBBX", 0x00, 0x0e, p->len, p->data, p->len);
                offset += bytes_placed;
                building_cluster = true;
                free_packet(p);
                l->erase(l->begin());
            } else {
                //appends to existing cluster packet
                bytes_placed = build_packet( &buf[offset], "BX", p->len, p->data, p->len);
                offset += bytes_placed;
                free_packet(p);
                l->erase(l->begin());
            }
        } else {
            /* can't create cluster or cluster is filled up */
            if(building_cluster) //has a previous cluster in progress
                break;
            //cluster is filled up
            bytes_placed = build_packet(buf, "X", p->data, p->len);
            free_packet(p);
            l->erase(l->begin());
            return bytes_placed;
        }
    }
    return offset;
}
```

EDIT 4: ended up using

```
else if(!building_cluster && p->len > MAX_CLUSTER_SIZE)
```

Comment: Do you understand the difference between boolean AND and boolean equality?

Comment: false and false is false. That's a fundamental piece of logic that C++ just took and used. It has nothing to do with computers at all. This is how it is in Math and everywhere else.

Comment: It _is_ real logic :) Consider `a dog has three legs AND a cat has five legs` - both sub-statements are false, and so is the combined statement.

Comment: The community really has a very bad habit of down voting entry level questions. The question is clear (in the sense that it is clear what is being asked), and clearly shows that the poster has put much thought into it, and is trying to understand why the code is not working the way the poster thinks it should. If it was possible, I would be reporting all people who down voted this question.

Comment: I suppose that if user3435580 asked me to return the lawnmower that I borrowed **and** fix it's engine which I broke, then doing neither would meet his requirements and it would be ok :)

Comment: Listen to your mother - two wrongs don't make a right!

Comment: The edits aren't helping.

Comment: In one of the comments on an answer you asked if there was a way to make two false be true and two true be true and only be false if they are different. There is: xor. It is represented by ^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are probably confusing `false && false` with double negation. While double negation becomes affirmative, the way this is expressed in C and C++ is `!false` or `!0`.

---

Your problem description and code is a little vague, but assuming what you really want is:

- if not in a combined packet but the current packet is too big,
  then send the current
- if in a combined packet but the current packet is too big,
  then send the combined, then send the current
- if not in a combined packet, but the current packet is small,
  then break to do the combine
- if in a combined packet but the current packet is small,
  then break to do the combine

Assuming the above is correct, then you only have to check to see if your current packet is small and will fit, otherwise you need to forward stuff.

---

Looking at your real code, there seems to be some confusing logic around whether you are currently building a cluster, and whether the current packet will fit into your cluster. You will benefit from following a simplified structure. The following pseudocode roughly follows what I had originally suggested, but tailored around how your loop actually operates.

```
bool start = true;
while (packet = head of list of packets) {
    if (packet will fit cluster) {
        if (start) {
            initialize cluster with packet;
            start = false;
        } else {
            add packet to cluster;
        }
        remove from head;
    } else {
        if (start) {
            initialize cluster with XL packet;
            remove from head;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Another confusion might be with "exclusive OR" and its kin.  Often constructs in English are ambiguous as to whether an AND or OR is inclusive or exclusive, since the language does not clearly distinguish.

Comment: Okay I break out if it's in a process of combining small packets and a big one is coming up next.. or if I didn't start combining and packet is too large then just not do anything it will send it by other code under it. Ah I just tried to make it all very short without making it big first and cutting it down later, i'll give it another shot.

Comment: In the pseudocode I provide, `break` indicates that you want to enter code to do the combining. This is because in your code, the `else` part had a comment that said `//don't combine, just send normally`, so I expanded out that comment into what I thought it would be.

Comment: Yeah I got a bit lazy I should of posted my actual code the break; indicated the loop i'm in which processes each packet before shipping them out when the loop breaks the function returns but the `//don't combine, just send normally` still has to fill the outgoing_buffer in that loop but yeah I got it now just need to code things more dirty not try to cram too much into a single line.

Comment: I posted the messed up code in another edit so you can see it. I'll try to redesign it again.

Answer (score 3):

The logical and has the following value table:

- true  && true => true
- true  && false => false
- false && true => false
- false && false => false

The result is only true if both operands are true. That's just the way it is. That **is** the real logic. If you don't believe me, just read the [Wiki article on boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_logic). It defines 'and' as above.

If you want a condition that evaluates to true if both operands are of the same value (e.g. both true or both false) then you can just use `if(a == b) ..`

Comment: It's not only the way it is, it's also how the word "and" is used in real life.

Comment: Yes but is there any logic that can determine if `false and false` becomes `true` and `true and true` becomes `true` only failure would be `false and true` or `true and false` ? that is my question.

Comment: @RetoKoradi - Actually, English is sometimes ambiguous in this regard (though more often with OR than with AND).

Comment: As I wrote - `(a == b)` would result in `true` if a and b are either both true or both false. Logical equality is the construct you're looking for. Not logical and. If you talk about the 'logical and' then you basically *always* talk about the logic I've detailed in my post.

Comment: @user3435580 -- For logic expressions you're talking about "exclusive NOR".

Comment: @Hot Licks ya I was looking for that `exclusive NOR`

Comment: @user3435580 which is also known as `logical equality`

Comment: @HotLicks: Yes, "or" in everyday language can be inclusive/exclusive depending on context, and is often ambiguous. Clearly the English language was not defined by computer scientists, because it's annoying. ;) I think "and" does not typically have that problem.

Comment: @RetoKoradi - And has a different problem in English, in that it is often interpreted as a logical "OR".

Answer (score 1):

The `&&` operation is not about *agreement*.

The `false` values here are not about *negation*.

The `false` values here are *values*.

The `&&` operation is a function, defined such that `true` `&&` `true` yeilds `true` and any other combination yeilds a value `false`.

In short `a && b` is shorthand for

```
a && b = f(a, b)
where
f(a, b) = { false | a = false, b = false
          { false | a = true, b = false
          { false | a = false, b = true
          { true  | a = true, b = true
```

`&&` is a computer operation that represents a *boolean* and operation.  It is formally defined within boolean number systems, and typically studied with boolean logic.

Comment: `The && operation is a function, defined such that false && false yeilds false and any other combination yeilds a value true.` Nope, that would be the logical **or** operator `||`.

Comment: @user2079303 Oh my goodness!  Your'e absolutely right!  I guess I got too carried away with the explanation to make sure the details were correct.  How embarrassing.  Thank you for the kind note.  I'll fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not about that kind of logic. It's about processing logic. In programming languages, when you have something like:

```
if (false && false) { ... }
```

The compiler sees options inside your `if` because of the `&&`. Then it evaluates the fisrt one, which is `false`. From that point, **there's no point on evaluating the next expression** - since the first one evaluates to `false`, there's no need to evaluate whatever follows `&&`, because that's an automatic whole false: `false &&`.

That's why the following is true:

- true && true => true
- true && false => false
- false && true => false
- false && false => false

...which, the way the compiler sees it (as in where it stops evaluating) is:

- true && true => true
- true && false => false
- false && [THIS IS NOT EVEN EVALUATED] => false
- false && [THIS IS NOT EVEN EVALUATED] => false

Answer (score 0):

Check out this "truth table":

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Truth_table_for_all_binary_logical_operators

The operation you're looking for is probably "exclusive NOR", which is the "NOT" of "exclusive OR".  Exclusive OR is represented by a circle with a `+` in it in mathematics, and, when used for bitwise computations, by the `^` symbol in C-based languages.  For "logical" computations exclusive OR can be represented by the "not equals" operator (and "exclusive NOR" is the "equals" operator).